# How do I loop through the images using class trigger

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I loop through all the images using the call trigger, when I click on the image a modal popup should show my text and image.

```js
var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal() {
  modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
}

function windowOnClick(event) {
  if (event.target === modal) {
    toggleModal();
  }
}
trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick);
}
```

```html
<div portfolio-item "> 
    <a class="trigger "><img src="images/techify.jpg "/></a>
    <div class="modal ">
    <div class="modal-content "> 
    <img class="modalimages " src ="Images/techify.jpg ">
    <div class="modal-text ">
    <p> It is all about a training institute</p>
    </div> 
    </div>
    </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="modal-content "> 
    <img class="modalimages " src ="Images/HairStyling.jpg "> 
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you want your popup modal show your image Continuous?

Comment: I would recommend using `id`'s for your identification, as you are using `querySelector`, which only returns the first element, and there is only one element that we can see that has the modal, modal-content, modalimages, modal-text, and trigger classes.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me can you pls send me the code using Ids

Answer (score 0):

Going by what you've supplied there are a few minor issues that would even prevent this from running, so I had to make some small changes to the code before I could even begin. One being the `}` placed at the end of your script.
Another being the `<div portfolio-item">` only having one `"`. 
This may or may not be what you're trying to accomplish, but we'd need more information in order to know.

```
<style>
.modal { display: block; }
.show-modal { display: none; }
</style>

<div portfolio-item> 
  <a class="trigger">
    <img src="images/techify.jpg"/>
  </a>
  <div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content"> 
      <img class="modalimages" src="Images/techify.jpg">
      <div class="modal-text">
        <p> It is all about a training institute</p>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-content"> 
    <img class="modalimages" src="Images/HairStyling.jpg"> 
  </div>
</div>  
<button class="close-button">Close Button</button>

<script>
var modal = document.querySelectorAll(".modal");
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
var closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");

function toggleModal() {
 for(i=0;i<modal.length;i++){
    modal[i].classList.toggle("show-modal");
  }
}

function windowOnClick(event) {
  if (event.target === modal) {
    toggleModal();
  }
}

trigger.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
closeButton.addEventListener("click", toggleModal);
window.addEventListener("click", windowOnClick); 
</script>
```

If you've looking for both images to be hidden on the first image click or by pressing the button (which I also had to add) you'll need to move the following code up by one line

```
<div class="modal-content"> 
  <img class="modalimages" src="Images/HairStyling.jpg"> 
</div>
```

Comment: This is working only when I click on the first image, and if I click on second image nothing happens. –

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add an event to every image, you could use some Javascript like this:

```
var images = document.querySelectorAll("img")

for( var i = 0 ; i < images.length ; i++ ) {
    images[i].addEventListener("click" someFunction)
}
```

This make it so that when any image is clicked, it calls the `someFunction` function

Comment: This is working only when I click on the first image, and if I click on second image nothing happens.